# mergeTwo CodingBat puzzle in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to solve [this](http://codingbat.com/prob/p139150) CodingBat problem:

> Start with two arrays of strings, A and B, each with its elements in alphabetical order and without duplicates. Return a new array containing the first N elements from the two arrays. The result array should be in alphabetical order and without duplicates. A and B will both have a length which is N or more. The best "linear" solution makes a single pass over A and B, taking advantage of the fact that they are in alphabetical order, copying elements directly to the new array.

```
mergeTwo({"a", "c", "z"}, {"b", "f", "z"}, 3) → {"a", "b", "c"}
mergeTwo({"a", "c", "z"}, {"c", "f", "z"}, 3) → {"a", "c", "f"}
mergeTwo({"f", "g", "z"}, {"c", "f", "g"}, 3) → {"c", "f", "g"}
```

Attempt:

```
public String[] mergeTwo(String[] a, String[] b, int n) {
    String[] op = new String[a.length + b.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        op[i] = a[i];
    }
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < op.length; i++) {
        if (op[i] == null) {
            j = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        op[j] = b[i];
        j++;
    }
    Arrays.sort(op);
    ArrayList<String> help = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < op.length - 1; i++) {
        if (op[i] != op[i + 1]) {
            help.add(op[i]);
        }
    }
    String[] res = new String[help.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < help.size(); i++) {
        res[i] = help.get(i);
    }
    String[] op2 = new String[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        op2[i] = res[i];
    }
    return op2;

}
```

So the problem is that all the tests pass except one:

[image]

Why is that?

Comment: Do you know how merge sort works?  If so, think about the merge phase.  If not, go learn about merge sort.

Comment: Your rules say "no duplicates" but the linked page showing the failure has identical elements in the two arrays. So do your examples at the top of the page.

Comment: @LeeMeador What do you mean? None of the results above have duplicates.

Comment: Ah ... no duplicates in a single array. The same value can be in both arrays. I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the line that has the problem:

```
 if (op[i] != op[i + 1]) {
```

You are looking for a pattern where the lsst of several identical strings doesn't match the next string.

In the failing case, there is no "next string" because there are exactly 3 unique strings.

One way to deal with that is to look for a pattern where this string is different than the last string but you don't really check the array for the last string (since the 1st array element has no last string). You use a variable, say `last`, to store the last string and transfer only when this element isn't equal to `last`.

Try this ...

```
String last = "";
for (int i = 0; i < op.length - 1; i++) {
    if (!op[i].equals(last)) {
        help.add(op[i]);
    }
    last = op[i];
}
```

Also note that in Java strings are compared with the `equals()` method.

Comment: Worked like a charm! TANKS!

Answer (score 1):

With Java8 it can be done with few simple rows of code:

```
public String[] mergeTwo(String[] a, String[] b, int n)
{
    Set<String> set = new HashSet();
    set.addAll(Arrays.asList(a));
    set.addAll(Arrays.asList(b));

    List<String> list = new ArrayList(set);

    return list.subList(0, n).toArray(new String[n]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
public String[] mergeTwo(String[] a, String[] b, int n) {
  String[] arr = new String[n];
  int aI = 0;
  int bI = 0;
        
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(a[aI].compareTo(b[bI]) < 0) {
      arr[i] = a[aI];
        aI++;
    } else if(a[aI].compareTo(b[bI]) > 0) {
      arr[i] = b[bI];
        bI++;
    } else {
      arr[i] = a[aI];
        aI++;
        bI++;
        }
    }
                                                                        
    return arr;
}
```